# Facebook Structured Message (Template) in conversation api

Tags: facebook, templates, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I'm working on linking a Messenger Bot with a Inbox Manager App.
Inbox Manager App need to get old messages from /conversation API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/conversation/messages to display old messages. However, I can't find proper data to display it.
Example:
1.[Button Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1zV4.png)

data in conversation:

```
{
 "message": "Đây là những chức năng chính của chúng tôi",  
 "shares": {
   "data": [
     {
       "id": "2020954901252437"
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

2.[Generic Template with 1 Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv5yR.png)
data in conversation:

```
{
 "message": "",
 "shares": {
   "data": [
     {
       "link": "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/api=1&destination=266+%C4%90%E1%BB%99i+C%E1%BA%A5n%2C+H%C3%A0+N%E1%BB%99i",
       "id": "2020947591253168",
       "name": "266 Đội Cấn, Hà Nội - 0904304070"
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

[Generic Template with 3 Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5wR1.png)
data in conversation:

```
{
 "message": "",
 "shares": {
   "data": [
     {
       "id": "2014708728543721",
       "name": "Sản phẩm nổi bật 123, Sản phẩm mới, Khuyến mãi"
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

Is there anyway I can get the full correct template data of a message like this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/template/generic#example_request
I suspect that id in shares.data is attachment_id in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/saving-assets/#asset_types, but I can't find a way to access attachment data anywhere.
Appreciate any help

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

FB Official said: "The /conversations" end point not return full data of message with template, you must store these template data before send to user to you DB and then you can display it. LOL